# SwiftUI: How to create a rectangle that fills available width and adjusts height to keep desired aspect ratio

Tags: swiftui

I am driven mad by a seemingly simple problem - in a `VStack` (inside `ScrollView`) I would like to have a rectangle that fits all available width, and sets its height so that it has a specified aspect ratio.

```
Rectangle()
    .fill(.brown)
    .aspectRatio(2, contentMode: .fit) // or .fill
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

This seems like it should work, but sometimes (depending on other elements inside ScrollView, which should have an infinite space available) SwiftUI decides:

1. that there isn't enough vertical space available, and with a `contentMode: .fit` the rectangle becomes smaller than I want (= it doesn't fill the whole width)
2. or that there is more then required height available, and with `contentMode: .fill` the rectangle fills available height, and becomes wider than viewport, with its content being cutoff by screen edge

I tried adding `.frame` modifier to `Rectangle`, but:

- `.frame(maxWidth: .inifinity)` seems to make no difference
- `.frame(maxWidth: .inifinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` causes the option `2` to always happen - the rectangle eats up all available height, and then the width is set accordingly.

**Basically I want a way to make `respect aspectRatio based on width` modifier, but have no idea how to accomplish this.**

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: ScrollView needs explicit concrete content dimensions, so any inifinity-s make it behaves unpredictable. I assume you have to combine it with external GeometryReader to give explicit width for that frame.

Comment: @Asperi Thank you! Do I understand right that I should put GeometryReader outside of the ScrollView, and pass down the available width (and then set it via .frame(width: height))?

Comment: @Asperi I tried this, it works, but my problem is that I need this component at various places inside app, sometimes inside other components (= its width is smaller than viewport), and once I put a small local GeometryReader at each of those places, it causes other layout problems (mainly that the reader reports zero height to outside, so the component overlaps stuff below it) :/.